# What is the current "standard" for setting up a development environment that supports remote collaboration as well as secure version control?

Tags: collaboration, versioning, hosting

What is the current "standard" for setting up a development environment that supports remote collaboration as well as secure version control?

Considering a virtual dedicated solution with vm for a web layer and a data layer, using VPN for each programmer. We're a small start-up that do both Microsoft and open-source development. Is there a set software tools or packages that are appropriate for a small shop and yet scalable?

Comment: This question will become out of date very quickly and hence "too localised". A question discussing techniques and tips for specific products would be better.

Comment: How do you expect "remote collaboration" to happen?  Is it enough to have a shared source repository?

Answer (score 2):

Coming from unix environment. I would set up servers (web layer, data layer, version control, and so on) the normal way. And then handle "remote" and "secure" with SSH, for example:

- Remote access: shell, X11, VNC, ...
- Most version control systems support ssh (svn, git, ...)
- port forwarding for light weight "VPN", for example accessing database

Business as usual, and with help of SSH making remote things "securely local".

Answer (score 0):

Git and any other DVCS supports remote users well.  And they can run over ssh, so are secure.